# How to setup property access via string name parameter in .NET

Tags: .net, reflection, properties

How can I write extension method "SetPropValue" that it works like:

```
myObject.SetPropValue("Address") = "blahblah"

// which does:
myObject.Address = "blahblah"
```

And also "GetPropValue":

```
Object address = myObject.GetPropValue("Address")
```

Comment: Good point @LarsTech.  I changed to object

Comment: There are scenarios where this is useful, for example think of a dynamic scenario where you would only know at run time what property you want to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not provide facilities for achieving the first syntax, because assignment operator does not allow overloading. You can use a more traditional syntax for the setter, though:

```
myObject.SetPropValue("Address", "blahblah");
```

Here is how you can do it:

```
public static void SetPropVal<T>(this object obj, string name, T val) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    obj.GetType().GetProperty(name)?.SetValue(obj, val);
}

public static T GetPropVal<T>(this object obj, string name) {
    if (obj == null) return default(T);
    var res = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name)?.GetValue(obj);
    return res != null ? (T)res : default(T);
}
```

Note that this approach makes sense only when string are *not* known at compile time, i.e. they come from a user or from configuration. When strings are known at compile time, casting to `dynamic` lets you achieve the same thing with a more readable syntax.

Comment: Thank you for this. The Scenario you describe where the strings come from configuration is exactly what I'm facing